# How to build project with local library on platformio?

Tags: c, embedded, lib, platformio, libopencm3

Problem: Cannot understand why the project is not building with local library.

I am getting following error on my terminal while building the project:

```
Linking .pio/build/genericSTM32F103C8/firmware.elf
.pio/build/genericSTM32F103C8/src/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text.startup.main+0x2): undefined reference to `clock_setup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio/build/genericSTM32F103C8/firmware.elf] Error 1
```

My project tree looks like this:

[image: Project tree]

As per the platformio lib readme I have added the following in src/main.c

```
#include <clock.h>
```

My config for platform io is:

```
[env:genericSTM32F103C8]
platform = ststm32
board = genericSTM32F103C8
framework = libopencm3
debug_tool = custom
debug_server =
  $PLATFORMIO_CORE_DIR/packages/tool-openocd/bin/openocd
  -f 
  /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink-v2.cfg
  -f
  $PLATFORMIO_CORE_DIR/packages/tool-openocd/scripts/target/stm32f1x.cfg
  lib_ldf_mode = chain+
```

clock.h contains:

```
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>

BEGIN_DECLS

static void clock_setup(void);

END_DECLS
```

clock.c contains:

```
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
#include "clock.h"

static void clock_setup(void)
{
    /* Extenal 16 MHz clock set to 72MHz using PLL */
    rcc_clock_setup_in_hse_16mhz_out_72mhz();

    /* Enable clock for DI DO ADC UART */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOB);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOC);

    /* Enable AFIO clock. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_AFIO);

    /* Enable Timer clock. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_TIM3);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_TIM4);

    /* Enable UART clock. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART1);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART2);

    /* Enable I2C clock. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_I2C2);

    /* Enable SPI2 clock. */
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_SPI2);

}
```

Comment: Replace  "static void clock_setup(void) "
by  "void clock_setup(void)"

static means that the function cannot be seen outside of file.

Comment: @YvonBlais Still it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you replaced it in the `.h` and the `.c`? And did you include `clock.h` properly? There is a big difference between `#include <clock.h>` and `#include "clock.h"` Maybe add `#include "lib/CLOCK/src/clock.h` or if you really want to use `<>` notation: add the `lib/CLOCK/src/` to the linker path?

Answer (score 0):

My current lib folder looks like this and the platformio's LDF can now find my local libraries.

> ```
> ├── clock
> │   ├── clock.c
> │   └── clock.h
> ├── di
> │   ├── di.c
> │   └── di.h
> ├── do
> │   ├── do.c
> │   └── do.h
> ├── i2c
> │   ├── adc_i2c.c
> │   └── adc_i2c.h
> ├── spi
> │   ├── spi.c
> │   └── spi.h
> └── uart
>     ├── debug_uart.c
>     ├── debug_uart.h
>     ├── display_uart.c
>     ├── display_uart.h
>     ├── modbus_uart.c
>     └── modbus_uart.h
> ```